# Does firebase require code to refresh auth?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

I am using Firebase Auth in my iOS app written in swift. I allow authentication via email/password, facebook and google. I am concerned that after a certain time the auth status needs to be refreshed by code I have to write.

Once firebase has successfully logged in a user does it expire? Or will he stay logged in for ever; until signed off by calling the firebase function? Is this the case for all ways of login (email, facebook, google)? I checked google firebase doc but could not find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once firebase has successfully logged in a user does it expire?

No when you authenticate the user for the first time he will always be authenticated unless he is deleted from the firebase console.

> Or will he stay logged in for ever; until signed off by calling the firebase function?

Yes he will stay logged in until you sign out the user example using:

```
 try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
```

Comment: Ok thats great news; no extra code to write! Thx for the help!

Comment: A small addition to this: the token that the app uses to identify the user is only valid for an hour. But the SDK refreshes that token automatically for you every 55 minutes or so.